# At what circumstances will the difficulty for the tasks of density evaluation and sampling be different?

Tags: machine-learning, sampling, autoregressive, density-estimation, normalizing-flow

In this tutorial video of [normalizing flow](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8XufsgG066A&t=0s), the presenter mentioned that for the original autoregressive flow, the density evaluation is fast and the sampling is slow. In contrast, for the inverse autoregressive flow, the sampling is fast and the density is slow. I could not understand why. Because both the density evaluation and the sampling need to know the PDF, should not these two tasks always possess the same difficulty level?

P.S. There is a [review paper about normalizing flow](https://arxiv.org/abs/1912.02762) that talks about the difference between the forward KL divergence and the reverse KL divergence. My gut feeling is that these the aforementioned question might be related to this, but I could not figure out how.